# How to create an AutoComplete in HTML/XHTML with the data pulled with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, autocomplete

My project is on JSF2 and I am trying to pull some reference data from the Server to be used in an Input (text) field on the front end.

Using the following link as the starting point

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp

Instead of using the Array of fixed values (Strings), I want to fetch the data dynamically from the Server. Here is my code that attempts to achieve the purpose:

```
var constituencies;
function retrieveConstituencies(){
  /* Load constituencies dynamically */  
  var mde=document.getElementById("mode").value;
  alert("mode is "+mde);
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      constituencies = this.responseText;
      alert(constituencies);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "/NominateServlet?mode="+mde, true);
  xhttp.send();
    
}
```

And here is my final code that calls the autocomplete function (similar to the example in the link provided above)

```
autocomplete(document.getElementById("vsInput"), constituencies);
```

I am badly stuck on this problem from last 3 days and the autocomplete method just does not takes the AJAX values. If anyone has solution for this, kindly share.

PS: I am not using PrimeFaces or JQuery because I want to use vanilla technologies.

Many Thanks

Comment: What does `autocomplete` expect as its second argument? Also, it would have to be called within the `onreadystatechange` function in order to work.

Answer (score 0):

XMLHttpRequest makes an **asynchronous** request. The "autocomplete" function is called before the request completed and the "constituencies" variable is set. You should call the "autocomplete" function after request to API is completed. Try like this:

```
if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
    const items = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    const input = document.getElementById("vsInput");
  
    autocomplete(input, items);
}
```